# can't run gradle task from other task

Tags: android, gradle, task

I have a Jenkins Job that is running some gradle task:

```
 gradle clean -Pendpoint=qab assembleFromJenkinsJob
```

Here is the task itself:

```
task assembleFromJenkinsJob << {

    logger.lifecycle("Value of 'endpoint': ${endpoint}")
    if (String.valueOf(endpoint).equalsIgnoreCase('qab')) {
        assembleJenkinsQa
    } else if (String.valueOf(endpoint).equalsIgnoreCase('prod')) {
        assembleRelease
    }
    else
        assembleJenkinsQa
}
```

The task `assembleFromJenkinsJob` is running:

```
:app:assembleFromJenkinsJob
Value of 'endpoint': qab
```

but `assembleJenkinsQa` or `assembleRelease`  are not running.

I even tried to do it like this `assembleRelease.execute()`
but nothing is happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should never call a task directly. Also you don't need to call a task but rather define a dependency. And, finally, in an *action*  (`<<`) it's too late for running a task.

Let me know it this works:

```
task assembleFromJenkinsJob {
    logger.lifecycle("Value of 'endpoint': ${endpoint}")

    if (String.valueOf(endpoint).equalsIgnoreCase('qab')) {
        dependsOn assembleJenkinsQa
    } else if (String.valueOf(endpoint).equalsIgnoreCase('prod')) {
        dependsOn assembleRelease
    } else
        dependsOn assembleJenkinsQa
}
```

Comment: Thanks sir. It says: Could not get unknown property 'endpoint' for task ':app:assembleFromJenkinsJob',  after i removed << . How to pass enpoint param from command line using your example?

Comment: Try as you did with `-Pendpoint=qab` and then in script use `project.endpoint`.

Comment: wow, this worked, thanks a lot. i should definitely learn about gradle build system

Answer (score 1):

I would advice the use of [finalizedBy](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.Task.html#org.gradle.api.Task:finalizedBy)

```
task assembleFromJenkinsJob {
    def ep = String.valueOf(endpoint).toLowerCase()
    logger.lifecycle("Value of 'endpoint': ${ep}")
    switch (ep) {
        case 'qab':
            finalizedBy 'assembleJenkinsQa'
            break
        case 'prod':
            finalizedBy 'assembleRelease'
            break
        default:
            finalizedBy 'assembleJenkinsQa'
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually it seems to work the opposite - it is `assembleFromJenkinsJob` that should finalize other tasks - like `check` from java plugin. In gradle it's called a [lifecycle task](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/more_about_tasks.html#sec:lifecycle_tasks).

Comment: But `switch` still can be used :)